# When a rapist deflowers a girl by force and is going to explain what he has committed to someone else

Tags: phrase-request

How would a native speaker say that they have deflowered a girl? In other words, a rapist who has had sex with a girl by force is explaining the event to his close friend
I am looking for the informal equivalent of this verb.

P.S. I guess "to take someone's virginity" doesn't work too. I need an informal equivalent for that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I think it's distasteful to teach learners how rapists talk among themselves.

Comment: I think this is a strange question but I'm assuming it's for a story or something. The rapist could say "*I raped a virgin*" to his close friend.

Comment: Are you looking for something informal or do you want slang or something vulgar? How a villain describes their evil deed seems like something you would want to be more than just informal. I think for questions like these, you might get a better response if you explained why you're asking.

Comment: "Popped her cherry" is an informal equivalent, as is "Did the deed", "Did the nasty", though these do not necessarily imply violence.

Comment: @ColleenV and other respectable people! Why are you trying to make a puzzle out of a simple question? Is it a church or mosque? We are learning and the street, informal or any sort of vulgarities are a part of any language. Why some people keep preventing people from learning some needed information? This question is considered necessary to be asked at least to me. Because what we find in dictionaries, does not encompass all the aspects. We have too look at a concept from many angles. There were only two possibilities which sounded too formal for a friendly discussion. That's all!

Comment: @A-friend perhaps this speaks to cultural differences, but for me it's extremely uncomfortable to talk in any kind of "detached" or "academic" way about what is a pretty horrible criminal act.  My answer is about the best I will do, and under the circumstances you might consider this a lesson in cultural niceties.

Comment: @Andrew yeah, a question so awkward and uncomfortable you shared a link of obsolete euphemisms that did not answer the question. Which ones have you heard, or would you recommend that the OP's imaginary character should use: *give someone a green gown*? What did you want to do, "lighten" the topic of sexual assault?

Comment: My comment was asking a question to try to understand what type of answer you would like and making a suggestion to mitigate some of the controversy to increase your chances of getting a suitable answer. If you want to invite controversy, that is your choice, but I think it is counter-productive. When the community is responding negatively to your question, it's best to see if you can edit your question to address their concerns.

Comment: @Mari-LouA  There are nice metaphors for sex, so it shouldn't be hard to recognize that there may be many *not-so-nice* metaphors.  That's about as far as I was willing to go -- but at the same time, it's disingenuous to pretend that only "nice" people speak English.  Half of the shows on TV depict all kinds of unsavory acts.  I didn't much like how this question was *phrased* but I don't think it couldn't be *asked* in a different and more euphemistic way.

Answer (score 2):

While this is a distasteful subject, fiction novels often contain material that is offensive or disturbing.  For example, I'm currently reading Stephen King, who loves to include all kinds of horrible things in his stories.  Language describes the awful and the beatific without fear or favor.

In this context there is no specific idiomatic expression.  There are, of course, any number of crude expressions for having sex, including some that *imply* violence or lack of consent.  Some of these you can find [on this website](http://reallifeglobal.com/40-ways-to-say-sex-synonyms-slang-and-collocations-explicit/) (toward the bottom), but there are as many others as creative people can come up with.  [Here's another list of some colorful historical examples](https://www.bustle.com/articles/69554-26-amazing-historical-euphemisms-for-sex-because-you-could-stand-to-have-your-corn-ground) that may not be accurate, but are amusing.

So a *rapist* might use any slang expression to describe the act, adding additional words to indicate the victim's virginity and perhaps also to suggest force -- but again, there is no "common" idiom to describe this specific act.

Comment: So do my offered choices work in informal language or a friendly conversation between two youths too @Andrew or they would sound a bit odd to be heard?

Comment: A "friendly" conversation?  That's a little disturbing to imagine that you think that's a normal topic of conversation for "friends" to have.  Perhaps if you gave some context why you need this -- like it's for an English-language novel you are writing -- we would feel a little better about the subject matter.  Otherwise I'm not comfortable suggesting idiomatic expressions.  Perhaps you need to watch more movies and TV shows that include these kind of heinous characters.

Comment: Not at all @Andrew. There is a misunderstanding here and doubtlessly a cultural gap. Let's change my question in this way; Imagine two "gangsters" who've been close growing up are talking about their memories and laughing at the innocent, sexual victims who they had some affairs with them in the past. They are at their 70's now and are going through their lives pleasant events. [These happenings can be considered peasant to such a category]. The dictionary suggestion for me, sounds too formal to be used here in such a conversation and between these types of people! Is it too offensive?!

Comment: I don't think so. But the problem is quite clear. I didn't make myself understood. I had to clarify my intent better..

Comment: Consensual sex, even between young people, is a very different thing from rape.

Answer (score 2):

The correct and only appropriate term is **rape**. It matters not one bit if the victim is married, in her fifties or just a young teenager. Non consensual forced sex, involving the penis (and I used the word *penis* because the OP talks about a man "deflowering" a girl), is always called **[rape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rape#Definitions)**.

In *real* life, would a rapist ever brag about ***raping*** an innocent woman to a friend? Would a rapist admit to *raping* a virgin, which suggests strongly that the victim was a young woman, possibly someone in her teens.

If his victim was fourteen years old, do you think he would be so stupid as to confess this heinous crime, which is sometimes called **[statutory rape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statutory_rape)**, or  **rape of a child** (ROAC), to a "friend"?

Comment: Rape is non-consensual sex. Children can not give consent legally, so even if a child is not "forced" to have sex, it's still rape. Whether a penis is involved or not is irrelevant. I understand why you put all that in there, but I think your (justifiably) strong emotion is making the answer harder to understand. If we're going to tackle this topic, in my opinion we should stick to talking about language in the answers. If you want to ask for clarification from the author about why a rapist is bragging about his crime I think a comment (or several) would be better.

Comment: @ColleenV  The Q is `How would a native speaker say that they have deflowered a girl?` *Rape* is the most idiomatic, and unambiguous term a native speaker would use. The phrase "I fucked a 17-year-old" is ambiguous, but "I raped a 17-year-old" is not.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with "rape" as an answer, I agree with it. It's all the other irrelevant stuff in the answer that's really talking about how outrageous it is for a rapist to brag about raping a virgin. It's just a suggestion, but I think the answer isn't clear. I'm reluctant to edit it because you seem attached to what you've written and I don't think it's "bad". I just think it could be better.

Comment: I'm not censoring. I am a strong believer that when you're teaching a language, euphemisms are really bad. I don't think I'm explaining what I mean well, so I think it would be better to leave it alone.

Comment: @ColleenV   The irrelevant stuff as you previously put it, is saying that the imagined scenario in the OP's imagination is wholly unrealistic.No one's even mentioned a thing about that goddamn stupid, and *extremely*  insulting  term "***deflowering***". What!? Are we crazy? The OP has the audacity to compare raping a young innocent woman to someone who **lost their virginity** in the 19th century.

Comment: @ColleenV It's a wiki community answer, anyone can edit it, so if you want to improve it, do so. I won't interfere.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52034/discussion-between-colleenv-and-mari-lou-a).